# React native, can't acess elements in array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a little problem accessing the elements in an array in react native.
I have the problem with the following code:

```
GetStockPrice = () => {
  var stockPrice = StockLogic.getStockPrice();
  console.log(stockPrice)
  for (let index = 0; index < stockPrice.length; index++) {
    console.log(stockPrice[index]);
  }
};
```

The StockLogic.getStockPrice() looks like this:

```
getStockPrice() {
  var stockPricesJSON = [];
  this.stocknames.forEach(stock => {
    var url =
      "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" +
      stock +
      "/batch?types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=10";
    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data =>
        stockPricesJSON.push(
          [data.quote.symbol, data.quote.open, data.quote.close, Number(((data.quote.open - data.quote.close)).toFixed(1))]
        )
      );
  });
  return stockPricesJSON;
}
```

If I run the GetStockPrice function, I only get the console.log() of the stockPrice that is passed from the other class. But the logs from the loop don't show up.

I guess that the problem is in the StockLogic, but I can't figure it out. 
I hope you can help me once again. 
Hope you have a nice day.
Iywern

Comment: You should check async/await to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both `fetch` and `forEach` are asyncrhonous, `stockPricesJSON` is being returned as an empty array.

For something like this you'll want to use `Promise.all`:

```
function getStockPrice() {
  var stockPricesJSON = [];
  var promises = this.stocknames.map(stock => {
    var url =
      "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" +
      stock +
      "/batch?types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=10";
    return fetch(url);
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(stocks) {
      stocks.forEach(function(stock) {
          //...your code
      })
  })
}
```

Note that you may need to call Promise.all two times which might look something like this:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(stocks) {
  var jsonpArr = stocks.map(function(stock) {
    return stock.jsonp();
  });
  Promise.all(jsonpArr).then(function(stocks) {
    stocks.forEach(function(stock) {
      //...your code here
    });
  });
});
```

And finally instead of returning that value I would suggest you store it with redux or your component state using `setState`. If this function does not belong to a component then I would suggesting wrapping the entire thing in a promise

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   //...your code
})
```

and calling `resolve()` on the result

To further improve this I would highly suggest using `async/await` along with a more modern syntax

```
const getStockPrice = () => {
  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let promises = this.stocknames.map(stock => {
        var url =
        "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" +
        stock +
        "/batch?types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=10";
        return fetch(url)
      })
      let result = await Promise.all(promises)
      let stocks = await Promise.all(result.map(r => r.jsonp()))
      stocks.forEach(stock => {
        //...your code
        resolve(result)
      })
    } catch(e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  })
}
```

And as always, documentation is your friend!

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

[async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is problem is related to the asynchronous way promises calls are executed. I had a similar problem and I had to run a function like getStockPrice within the response section of your code and assign the result to a state variable.